# PHP returns source code to my AJAX call instead of string

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this AJAX call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $.ajax({
                url:'test.php',
                type:'GET', 
                datatype: "json",
                success:function(data)
                {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error:function()
                {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
    });
</script>
```

and my test.php contains this:

```
<?php
    echo json_encode("pepperoni pizza");
    exit;
?>
```

However, my alert ends up showing *all* the PHP code instead of just "pepperoni pizza"

I have looked around quite a bit but haven't found a post that completely solves my problem. Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: Is that test.php being loaded when ypu are reading it via browser ? That going to test.php in url bar ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your web server is not configured to use PHP for interpretation of `.php` files.